# How to check if a number that starts with a letter

Tags: javascript, letter

I have a code below that matches a remainder of an 8 digit number to a letter when divided by 23.

```
function dniLetter( dni ) {

var lockup = 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE'
var result = ''; 
var remainder = dni % 23;
result = lockup.charAt(remainder)

return result; }
```

How could I improve if the number starts with a negative number (like -2) or start with a letter (A1234567)?

Comment: What would you want it to *do* in those cases?

Comment: What do you want to **do** if it is a negative number or if it comes with a letter?

Comment: does it matter what he is trying to do with that function?

Comment: `function isLetter(str) {
  return str.length === 1 && str.match(/[a-z]/i);
}`

Answer (score 1):

For the negative numbers, you should try replacing `dni % 23` by `((dni % 23) + 23) % 23`. It will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions.

`/^[a-zA-Z-]/.test(yourString)` returns true on the specified conditions (and even if it starts with '-A' for instance).